# Create a Sitemap.xml in classic ASP with hreflang alternate urls

Tags: xml, asp-classic, sitemap, xmldom

I'm forced to work in classic ASP for an old project that need some updtate.
I need to create a sitemap with this schema:

```
<url>
<loc>URL_BASE</loc>
<lastmod>DATE</lastmod>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="URL_IT"/>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="URL_EN"/>
</url>
```

I've found a asp script that create a simple sitemap.xml but more simple and without the "lastmod" and the alternate urls.

```
Dim theDom, theRoot, theParent,theChild, theID, docInstruction

const NODE_ELEMENT = 1
const xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

Set theDom = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Set theRoot = theDom.createElement("urlset")

Set theID = theDom.createAttribute("xmlns")
theID.Text = xmlNs
theRoot.setAttributeNode theID
theDom.appendChild theRoot

Set theParent = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "url", xmlns)     
Set theChild = theDom.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "loc", xmlns)
theChild.Text = "http://someURL.com"
theRoot.appendChild theParent
theParent.appendChild theChild

Set docInstruction = theDom.createProcessingInstruction("xml","version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'")
theDom.insertBefore docInstruction, theDom.childNodes(0)
theDom.Save Server.MapPath("sitemap.xml")
```

There is a way to create a .xml file like the schema i need?
I've tried to find out how to made it without any success.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: So you have found some code somewhere and now you look for someone to rewrite it for you. That's not a question. That's a work assignment.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, my problem is how to add the "xhtml:link" part as a child. I don't need someone that write for me a code. If you know how to create a child for alternate url i will add to my code by myself. Thanks